# $lookup: одно поле

Tags: mongodb

добрый день.

имеются две коллекции, например такие:

```
db.tags.find()

{_id:ObjectID(...),"text":"text1", "tags":"tag1"},
{_id:ObjectID(...),"text":"text2", "tags":["tag2", "tag3"]},
{_id:ObjectID(...),"text":"text3", "tags":["tag1", "tag3"]}
```

и

```
db.tagdetails.find()

{_id:ObjectID(...),"tagname":"tag1","det":"x"},
{_id:ObjectID(...),"tagname":"tag2","det":"y"}
```

делаем $lookup:

```
db.tags.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0, tags:1, text:1}}, {$unwind:"$tags"}, {$lookup: {from:"tagdetails", localField:"tags", foreignField:"tagname", as:"t"}}])
```

вроде всё работает, но на выходе получается коллекция вроде такой:

```
{"text":..., "tags":..., "t": [{"_id":..., "tagname":..., "det":...}]}
```

подробнее:

```
{"text":"posttext", "tags":"tag1", "t":[{"_id":ObjectID..., "tagname": "tag1", "det":"x"}]}
{"text":"posttext2", "tags":"tag2", "t":[{"_id":ObjectID..., "tagname": "tag2", "det":"y"}]}
{"text":"posttext2", "tags":"tag3", "t":[]}
{"text":"posttext3", "tags":"tag1", "t":[{"_id":ObjectID..., "tagname": "tag1", "det":"x"}]}
{"text":"posttext3", "tags":"tag3", "t":[]}
```

т.е., понятно, лукап вкладывает документ из второй коллекции целиком. мне это не надо. надо получить документ вида:

```
{"text":..., "tags":..., "det":...}
```

Т.е. из второй коллекции только одно поле. Не могу понять, как это сделать. Исключить его с помощью $project я не могу, появляется ошибка:

```
The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion
```

Comment: Пожалуйста убираете все эти `...`  и пишите заначение эти поля. Тоже скажите сколько элементов  в массиве после `$lookup`?

Comment: Значения _id, разумеется, имеют вид ObjectId("59624671bf7c5ea69b2d6206"). Я не вижу абсолютно никакого смысла это здесь писать. Указанная команда aggregate возвращает 5 документов. Результат её работы отредактировал

Comment: Когда вы задаете вопрос в MongoDB, Я очень совертую что вы писали валидный BSON документ. Если думаете что писать некотые поля, то нинадо писать `...`  в месте них. Некторые не опитные MongoDB пользователи бы хотели проверить свой ответ локальный перед чем его писать на сайте. Я знаю о чем я говорию

Comment: не вижу смысла писать кракозябры вида ObjectId("59624671bf7c5ea69b2d6206"). _id это стандартное id поле, которое монго добавляет автоматически с идентификаторами подобного вида

Comment: Предложенная Вами правка, на мой взгляд, является неправильной, и вводит в заблуждение. Команда db.collection.find(), безусловно, выведет содержимое документов коллекции вместе с полем _id, его убирать, как ненужное, не надо. Вполне возможно, что оно и правда ненужное, однако всё же данная команда его выводит. Также указанный лукап вкладывает документ из присоединённой коллекции тоже вместе с полем _id из этой коллекции.

Comment: повторюсь, поле _id создаётся автоматически. если вы создадите ранее не существовавшую коллекцию, указав в команде insert какие-то поля, монго автоматически добавит к этим полям ещё одно - поле _id, сгенерировав идентификаторы указанного вида.

Answer (score 0):

После **$lookup** сделайте **$unwind** по полю "t" и после применяйте **$project** с нужными полями.